# How to pull each game value if main value if true JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

PHP File for getting json value

```
$url = 'demo.json'; // path to your JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$characters =  json_decode($data, true); // decode the JSON feed
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>

        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($characters['events'][0]['offers'][0]['outcomes'] as $character) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $character['id']; ?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you for the solutions. 
only need to show data if main value is true from each game. Thanks Dhamo

Comment: check if condition in foreach loop.

Comment: Do you want to check each iteration event data exist? Right?

Comment: sometimes $offers['main'] values comes has 1 instead of Boolean .Check my code below its working for me

Comment: Need to add one more forloop. Check my code below

Comment: @dhamo now i am trying to pull data if  "label":"Point Spread", <?php 
     foreach ($characters['events'] as $events){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$events['startDate']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$events['name']."</td>";
    foreach ($events['offers'] as $offers){
        if($offers['main']==true || $offers['main']==1){
            foreach ($offers['outcomes'] as $character) :  if($offers['label']=='Point Spread' ){?> <td>    <?php echo $offers['outcomes'][0]['line'].'('.$offers['outcomes'][0]['oddsAmerican'].')</td>'; }?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check Main Conditions In for Loop**

```
  <?php 

    foreach ($characters['events'] as $events){
    foreach ($events['offers'] as $offers){
        if($offers['main']==true || $offers['main']==1){
            foreach ($offers['outcomes'] as $character) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td> <?php echo $character['id']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $character['label']; ?></td>    
                    <td> <?php echo $character['line']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $character['oddsAmerican']; ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $character['participant']; ?></td>
                </tr>
        <?php endforeach;

    }
}
}?>
```

Comment: Great its working @dhamo but its only showing 1 game data . How can i show all game data . if i am changing [0] to [1] then showing other game data $characters['events'][1]['offers']